# Объявление std::forward

Tags: c++, std-forward

Почему std::forward объявлён так?

```
  template <class _Ty>
_NODISCARD constexpr _Ty&& forward(
    remove_reference_t<_Ty>& _Arg) noexcept;
```

Если с точки зрения пользовательского интерфейса лучше было написать так

```
   template <class _Ty>
_NODISCARD constexpr auto forward(
     _Ty&& _Arg) noexcept -> decltype(_Arg);
```

Comment: It is the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(У `std::forward` две перегрузки - основная и вспомогательная. Из вашего вопроса не ясно, является ли предложенный вами вариант заменой для основной перегрузки или для них обеих сразу. Но в любом случае: )

Не понимаю вашего предложения в принципе. Основная функциональность `std::forward` (первая перегрузка из двух) заключается в непосредственном форвардинге аргументов. Аргументы - это *именованные* переменные. И как все именованные переменные, они являются lvalue. Именно поэтому первая перегрузка `std::forward` принимает именно lvalue-ссылку в качестве аргумента. Задача `std::forward` - в зависимости от типа `_Ty` либо выполнить конвертацию lvalue в xvalue (как это делает `std::move`), либо оставить lvalue как lvalue.

Например, в контексте функции

```
template <typename T> void foo(T &&t)
{
  std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

вызванной с rvalue аргументом

```
foo(42);
```

тип `T` будет дедуцирован как `int`. При этом выражение `t` внутри `foo` является lvalue.

В результате такой дедукции предложенная вами версия `std::forward` получит `_Ty == int` и будет иметь параметр типа `int &&`. Но, как сказано выше, внутри `foo` выражение `t` является lvalue. Его невозможно будет передать в ваше `std::forward`, ибо последнее будет требовать rvalue в качестве аргумента. То есть c вашей версией `std::forward` этот пример даже не будет компилироваться.

---

Отдельно можно заметить, что в объявлении параметра

```
remove_reference_t<_Ty>& _Arg
```

тип `_Ty` находится в *недедуцируемом контексте* (non-deduced context), что *заставляет* пользователя при вызове `std::forward` всегда явно руками указывать шаблонный аргумент. Это критически важно для правильной функциональности `std::forward`.

В вашем же варианте фактически получилась *универсальная ссылка*, т.е. шаблонный аргумент вдруг является дедуцируемым. Автоматически дедуцируемого форвардинга в C++ пока что реализовать невозможно.

Comment: Понятно, но можете объяснить, что значит "дедуктируемый"?Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Dogi Van: (Исправил везде на "дедуцируемый"). Я имею в виду обычную дедукцию шаблонных аргументов. Если вы не знаете, что это такое, то надо читать литературу. В двух словах это не объяснить.